# TileServer GL does not preview when using config file

Tags: tileserver-gl

I am trying to use TileServer GL to serve two kinds of data: osm vector and blue marble raster. Vector data was downloaded from their site for free, while blue marble I have assembled and tiled myself using GDAL.

Now, issue is, without a config file, TileServerGL only serves one mbtiles file. However, once I switch to a config file, its preview capabilities stop working. Even though I was able to access the data via Leaflet webpage I wrote!

Here is my config.json

```
{
  "options": {
    "paths": {
      "root": "",
      "fonts": "fonts",
      "sprites": "",
      "icons": "",
      "styles": "styles",
      "mbtiles": ""
    },
    "domains": [
      "0.0.0.0:8080"
    ],
    "formatQuality": {
      "jpeg": 80,
      "webp": 90
    },
    "maxScaleFactor": 18,
    "maxSize": 2048,
    "pbfAlias": "pbf",
    "serveAllFonts": false,
    "serveAllStyles": false,
    "serveStaticMaps": true,
    "allowRemoteMarkerIcons": true,
    "tileMargin": 0
  },
  "styles": {
    "basic-preview": {
      "style": "basic-preview/style.json"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "maptiler-osm-2020-02-10-v3.11-planet": {
      "mbtiles": "maptiler-osm-2020-02-10-v3.11-planet.mbtiles"
    },
    "z8": {
      "mbtiles": "z8.mbtiles"
    }
  }
}
```

This results in a server that can serve properly - I have one STYLES entry, with a working title image, and two DATA entries, again, with a working blue marble image.

But clicking Viewer, View, Raster, Vector shows empty map, nothing is displayed. That is despite the fact that it works in Leaflet!

How to fix this?